# Do an action after two rounds of a for loop

Tags: php, loops, for-loop

I've got a `$identifier`, `$start_number` and `$end_number`.

- The start number is the number where the `for` loop should start
  counting from
- The end number is where the loop should stop counting
- The identifier determinates how much is getting added to the start number

This for loops looks something like this:

```
$start_number = 102;
$end_number = 1051;
$identifier = 24;

for($i = $start_number; $i <= $end_number; $i += $identifier) {
    //The first two times, add 1 to the identifier
    //The second two times (we're at 4 now) add 5 to the identifier
    //The third two times (were at 6 now) add 10 to the identifier
    //The fourth two times (we're at 8 now) add 20 to the identifier
    //etc...
}
```

I want it to add a dynamic number (which changes) to the `$identifier` each 2 times it loops, how do i do this?

Comment: You sad: "The start number is the number where the for loop should start counting from" so why `for($i = $identifier;`?

Comment: @lolka_bolka Oow wait,,, your right.. one second

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just keep track of where you are in your loop by using a counter. Then you can use the modulus operator to determine if it an even number iteration. You can add the appropriate value by using an array to store the values to add to `$identifier` with the count being the key to get your correct value.

```
$start_number = 102;
$end_number = 1051;
$identifier = 24;
$add = array(
    2 => 1,
    4 => 5,
    6 => 10,
    8 => 20
);

$count = 1;
for($i = $start_number; $i <= $end_number; $i += $identifier) {
    if ($count % 2 === 0) {
        $identifier += $add[$count];
    }
    $count++;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this did the job. Is there another way then using an array? That the values getting automaticly generated (1, 5, 10, 20) It's getting doubled every time.

Comment: @Bas Of course. A simple loop can take care of that.

Comment: Could you give me an example?

Comment: That would be for another question. It's too long for a comment.

Comment: true that. Thanks anyways :)

Answer (score 1):

```
for($i = $identifier; $i <= $end_number; $i += $identifier) {
   if($i%2 == 0){
   //do your work
  }
}
```

Comment: That is not correct: 'The identifier determinates how much is getting added to the start number' -- think of `$identifier` value beeing 3. And it's even missing the start values. If you had `$start_number == 2` this would be true for the first loop iteration.

Comment: the John Conde answer is best